# How do I determine what OS dependency packages are required for a Haskell executable?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've just compiled an executable with `stack build` and then just copying over the executable to a different machine, however running the application results in:

```
./app: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing I need to install some packages from the appropriate Linux distro's packages - but is there more efficient way then googling for each error that comes up and trying to identify the package?

I've tried running executable within some docker images:
`fpco/haskell-scratch`, `debian:stretch-slim` which all result in the same behaviour:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/abcxyz fpco/haskell-scratch sh
# /abcxyz/app
/abcxyz/app: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

**Update**

With the debian image I installed openssl:

`apt-get install openssl`

New error:

/abcxyz/app: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

`apt-get install libgmp-dev`

And it works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually not specific to Haskell, but rather to the way Linux dynamically links shared libraries. You can use `ldd <file>`:

```
% ldd ./StateSort
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd29385000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd986bd1000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fd98693e000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd986736000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd986532000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd986314000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd985f5c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd986f1d000)
```

If there are missing libraries, you will notice them right away: the right hand side with the path to the `so` file will be absent.

You will then have to refer to your Linux distro's package management system to find out what package may contain the desired `so` file. For Ubuntu you would use `apt-file`, for ArchLinux − `pkgfile`, and so on.

I must warn you that `ldd` actually executes some of the code found in a file, so a malicious program may take over and wreak havoc. If you want to dissect an executable of unknown origin this way, you must do so in a disposable forensic containment. As I understand, this is not applicable in the case at hand, but nevertheless I must warn you.